# To Recursively call variable value in eval

Tags: python, dictionary

Actually i have two dict "d" and "d1",where dict "d" contains some groups,and dict "d1" contains formulas.

```
d = {
 'a;0': {'2010': 'A;B', 'p': '', 'r': ''},
 'a;1': {'2010': '1;',  'p': '', 'r': ''},
 'a;2': {'2010': '7;8', 'p': '', 'r': ''},
 'b;0': {'2010': 'C;D', 'p': '', 'r': ''},
 'b;1': {'2010': '5;6', 'p': '', 'r': ''}
}
```

Here `a;0` contains Tags in the field `2010` (i.e A,B) and `b;0` is one more group with tags(C,D), `a;1`, `a;2` are the sub-groups of `a;0` containing value in field `2010` ('1','') and ('7','8') similarly `b;1` is sub-group in `b;0` contain values ('5','6').

```
d1 = {
  'F':{'p':'','r':'','2010':'A+B'},
  'G':{'p':'','r':'','2010':'F+A'}
}
```

This is the formula dict,where `F='A+B` and `G=F+A`, when i try to run this with below code it prints only `F` value not `G` value. The code i used is

```
tag=[]
d2={}
for k,v in d.items():
    if ';' in k: # i am checking in main dict is their any subgroups
        a=k.split(';')
if a[1]=='0': # i am splitting it and checking if list zero bcoz main groups contain 0 ie('a;0','b;0') 
        pass
else:
        tag=d[a[0]+';0']['2010'].split(";")#splitting main group into tags
        value=v['2010'].split(";") #contain values 
        c=[0 if value[i]=='' else value[i] for i in range(len(value))]# if any balnk value in list values make it zero.bcoz i should use it eval
        for i in range(len(c)): #converting to int 
            try:
                c[i]=int(c[i])
            except ValueError:
                c[i]=str(c[i])
        x=dict(zip(tag,c)) # making a dict of tag n values for each iteration
        print '<%s>'%a[0] #printing group name
        for i in range(len(value)):
            if value[i]=='':
                tag[i]=''
            else:
                print '<%s>%s<%s>'%(tag[i],value[i],tag[i])
        for k,v in d1.items():
            try:
                d2[k]={'p':'','r':'','2010':eval(d1[k]['2010'],x)} #trying to use eval
            except NameError:
                continue
        print '</%s>'%a[0]
```

From this its printing in group but the value of 'G' is not calculated

Output from this is

```
<a>
<A>7</A>
<B>8</A>
<F>15</F>
</a>
<a>
<A>1</A>
<F>1</F>
</a>
<b>
<C>5</C>
<D>6</D>
</b>
```

But what i want in output is

```
<a>
<A>7</A>
<B>8</A>
<F>15</F>
<G>22</G>
</a>
<a>
<A>1</A>
<F>1</F>
</a>
<b>
<C>5</C>
<D>6</D>
</b>
```

i want 'G' value to be printed in group

pls anyone help me,thanks in advance

Comment: @aquavitae now i edited can u help now pls

Comment: Stop using eval. Seriously, stop it.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is really not easy to read.  After looking at it for half an hour I still can't figure out what its doing.  A few general pointers:

- Read and apply [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).
- Use more descriptive names.  The best name you've got there is "value", which actually seems to be a tuple of values.  Also avoid reusing the same names in different places, especially loops.  You have nested loops like this, which is just asking for trouble.
- Considering refactoring your code into functions which do specific things.  And name them appropriately.
- Add [good comments](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#comments) explaining what you're doing.

If you do all this you'll probably find the bug on your own fairly easily, but if not then post back with more readable code.